# CakePHP Find Condition Breaking Submit

Tags: php, cakephp

When using the conditions paramater of find, the user id doesn't submit along with the other fields.

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Thing->create();
            if ($this->Thing->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Thing has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Thing could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }

$users = $this->Thing->User->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('User.username'),
            'conditions' => array('User.ownedby' => '3')
            ));
    $this->set(compact('users'));}
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="things form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Thing'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Thing'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
    ?>

    <div id="user-info">
    </div>

    </fieldset>

    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'
    )); ?>

</div>
```

However, when I omit the condition parameter, it submits just fine. Any ideas? In case you were wondering, I'm using the conditions parameter to sort the list of users that results in the select dropdown this creates.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "submit" if there's no form to submit :S You mean that the `$users` array doesn't fill the fields with what you want?

Comment: I've edited to show the entirety of my code for reference. The fields fill just fine, but when I use the conditions parameter the Thing saves but without an associated userid. When removing the conditions parameter however, the Thing saves just fine.

Comment: Try to see the html code the FormHelper outputs, is the name of the user_id field correct? Something like `data[Thing][user_id]` ?

Comment: data[Thing][user_id] is the output when the condition is added and when I take it out. The only difference being that without the condition more users are returned (due to the "ownedby" condition). =[

Comment: What does the `conditions` parameter have to do with the save?  It's not even hitting the `condition` until plenty after the save.  Might try re-writing the question/explanation part of your question so we have a clue what you're talking about :)

Comment: The conditions parameter is populating the dropdown that displays a list of usernames to select. When a username is selected, ajax creates an additional form in the .user-info div that is data[Thing][weight]. Regardless of the bearing conditions has on a save, I have found that without it my data saves just fine but with it, it does not.

Comment: There's something off about the data you're providing or the data that you're trying to submit...etc.  There is no way a 'conditions' parameter on a find that's done AFTER the save is affecting the save itself.  Granted, providing incorrect data that's generated FROM the condition might be the issue, but - we don't know your database/data...etc

Comment: Because the condition is filtering the array for the dropdown, it has to be something in that process (aka the FROM). Is there a piece of information missing from my question that might provide a better context for the problem?